# terraform aws: ecs dosn't deploy newest taskdefinition

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws, aws-fargate

I'm facing a little problem with my terraform deployment.

A new task definition is created during deployment. I then also see this in the web console.
ecs should now actually use this new task definition and update it. Instead, the most recent revision is deployed again.

My expectation would be that if I create a new task definition and pass the arn from that to ecs, that it will be deployed.

Unfortunately, I have no idea where to go from here.

I have created an ecs service with the following config:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "service" {
  name                               = "${var.appPrefix}-api-service-${var.envPrefix}"
  cluster                            = var.ecsClusterId
  task_definition                    = aws_ecs_task_definition.ecsTaskDefinition.arn
  platform_version                   = "1.3.0"
  desired_count                      = 1
  deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = 50
  deployment_maximum_percent         = 200
  launch_type                        = "FARGATE"
  scheduling_strategy                = "REPLICA"
  wait_for_steady_state              = true
  force_new_deployment               = true

  network_configuration {
    security_groups  = [var.ecsSecurityGroupId]
    subnets          = [var.privateSubnet1Id, var.privateSubnet2Id]
    assign_public_ip = false
  }

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = var.targetGroupId
    container_name   = var.containerName
    container_port   = var.httpPort
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [task_definition, desired_count]
  }
}
```

My task definition looks like this:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "ecsTaskDefinition" {
  family                   = "${var.appPrefix}-api-ECSTaskDefinition"
  task_role_arn            = var.ecsTaskRoleArn
  execution_role_arn       = var.ecsTaskExecutionRoleArn
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  cpu                      = "512"
  memory                   = "1024"
  container_definitions    = <<DEFINITION
[...]
DEFINITION
}
```

~edit:
this is the terraform log:

```
# module.ecs_api_module.aws_ecs_task_definition.ecsTaskDefinition must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "ecsTaskDefinition" {
~ arn                      = "arn:aws:ecs:*****:********:task-definition/project-name-api-ECSTaskDefinition:507" -> (known after apply)
~ container_definitions    = (sensitive) # forces replacement
~ id                       = "project-name-api-ECSTaskDefinition" -> (known after apply)
- ipc_mode                 = "" -> null
- pid_mode                 = "" -> null
~ revision                 = 507 -> (known after apply)
- tags                     = {} -> null
~ tags_all                 = {} -> (known after apply)
# (8 unchanged attributes hidden)
}
```

Comment: What does the `terraform plan` output say? Also, are you sure it's the new task definition that isn't being updated, or could it be the new docker image isn't being deployed?

Comment: @MarkB i added the logs. I load the docker image from gitlab and that is build in a ci step before. in the webconsole for ecs, i see that there isn't the latest revision deployed. And i checked before deployment that 507 was the latest revision. now it is 508, but it has not been deployed in ecs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `ignore_changes` attribute from the `ecs_service` resource or least remove the `task_definition`.

```
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [desired_count]
  }
```

Comment: somehow very obvious and yet somehow overlooked... thank you